# Отладка xdebug перестала работать

Tags: php, apache, netbeans, xdebug

Всегда ставил `xdebug` по http://stafox.ru/install-and-configure-xdebug/#more-2109, все замечательно работало (ну тогда у меня был `Windows XP`).
Сейчас стоит `8.1`, но при отладке запускается страничка, в `netbeans` доступна только кнопка `*Finish debugger session*` и точки прерывания как будто для красоты висят.

В чем может быть ошибка?

Часть файла `php.ini`:

```
[xdebug]  
zend_extension = \usr\local\php5\ext\php_xdebug-2.2.5-5.4-vc9.dll  
xdebug.auto_trace = 0  
xdebug.default_enable = 1  
xdebug.idekey = netbeans-xdebug  
xdebug.overload_var_dump = 1  
xdebug.profiler_enable = 0  
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 1  
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="/tmp/xdebug/profiler/"  
xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%u"  
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1  
xdebug.remote_enable = 0  
xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp  
xdebug.remote_host = 127.0.0.1  
xdebug.remote_log = "/tmp/xdebug/xdebug.log"  
xdebug.remote_port = 9000  
xdebug.show_local_vars = 1  
xdebug.trace_output_dir = "/tmp"  
xdebug.var_display_max_depth = 6
```

Comment: Все винды после ХР получили ограничения на выполнение/доступ к файлам, папкам ... Думаю,  что надо копать в эту сторону.

Comment: Так я все ставил из под админа...

Comment: Правильно, а Netbeans рабодает под обычного пользователя попробуйте запустить  Netbeans под админа должно начать работать :).

Comment: Но на самом деле это не решение. Где то надо поменять права доступа... Кстати посканируйте порты 9000 может быть просто закрыт/неоткрыт ...

Comment: да нет же, у меня в самом ярлычке, запускающем *netbeans*, стоит галка запускать из под админа А насчет портов, ща просканирую

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20914636/open-windows-firewall-for-xdebug

Answer (score 3):

Все получилось, просто параметр `xdebug.remote_enable` нужно было выставить в `1` (там `0` по умолчанию).